# Initialize constants which are instance of complex class/struct (C++)

Tags: class, c++11, struct, initialization

I often want to define several constants which are instances of common `class` or `struct`. I didn't figured out any way how to do it when class contains pointers to other structs or dynamic arrays.

**Example:**

I want to write header file `Solids.h` which defines general `class Solid` and than define several constant instances like `Tetrahedron, Cube, Octahedron, Icosahedron`.

Following solution does not work: compiler complains that it is unable initialize pointers in `Solid Tetrahedron`

`Solids.h|45|error: cannot convert ‘Vec3d (*)[4] {aka Vec3TYPE<double> (*)[4]}’ to ‘Vec3d* {aka Vec3TYPE<double>*}’ in initialization|`

```
#ifndef  Solids_h
#define  Solids_h

#include "Vec2.h"
#include "Vec3.h"

class Solid{ public:
    int nvert;
    int nedge;
    int ntri;
    Vec3d * verts;
    Vec2i * edges;
    Vec3i * tris;
};

namespace Solids{

    // ==== Tetrahedron
    const static int Tetrahedron_nverts = 4;
    const static int Tetrahedron_nedges = 6;
    const static int Tetrahedron_ntris  = 4;
    static Vec3d     Tetrahedron_verts   [Tetrahedron_nverts]   = { {-1.0d,-1.0d,-1.0d}, {+1.0d,+1.0d,-1.0d}, {-1.0d,+1.0d,+1.0d}, {+1.0d,-1.0d,+1.0d} };
    static Vec2i     Tetrahedron_edges   [Tetrahedron_nedges] = { {0,1},{0,2},{0,3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}};
    static Vec3i     Tetrahedron_tris    [Tetrahedron_ntris] = { {0,2,1},{0,1,3},{0,3,2},{1,2,3} };

    const static Solid Tetrahedron = (Solid){Tetrahedron_nverts,Tetrahedron_nedges,Tetrahedron_ntris, &Tetrahedron_verts,&Tetrahedron_edges,&Tetrahedron_tris};
};

#endif
```

Comment: Why have you multiplied your counts by 2 and 3?  The array size specifies the number of elements like `Vec2i` or `Vec3i`, not the total number of ints used to create them.  So this is actually putting unneeded default-constructed vectors at the end of your arrays.

Comment: aschepler - aha sorry, my implementation was slightly different(it were `int *` not `Vec *`), I forgot this `*2` and `*3` when I was formating the code for this question. I corrected it now

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to array (like `&Tetrahedron_verts`) is different from a pointer to element (like `Vec3d * verts`).  You probably want the pointer `verts` to point at the first element of the array, which will let you do things like `Tetrahedron.verts[k]`.

So you could do `&Tetrahedron_verts[0]`, which would be valid.

But you don't need to, since most of the time the name of an array automatically decays to a pointer to the first element:

```
const static Solid Tetrahedron = {
    Tetrahedron_nverts, Tetrahedron_nedges, Tetrahedron_ntris,
    Tetrahedron_verts, Tetrahedron_edges, Tetrahedron_tris
};
```

Note you also don't need the `(Solid)` type name before the aggregate initializer.